In qgis2threejs plugin 3D view, how do I hide the sides of the generated DEM layer?
I have two DEM layers. Using the qgis2threejs plugin, the DEM layers are modelled as a solid, with solid sides. Is it possible to remove these sides so that the DEM layers are visualized as a thin 3D element?


I have tried clipping the DEM layers with a polygon that is slightly smaller than the model area, however, the sides are still being generated. Is there any way to remove them?
QGis version: 3.34.10-Prizren
Qgis2threejs version: 2.7.3
